# String serialized by JSON.NET always has some "\" in it

Tags: php, .net, http-post, json.net

I've been using Json.net to serialized my objects and send it to my PHP server by POST method. The problem is the data sent to my server always has some `\` in the result that it printed into the website view (it's fine if I send POST data directly to database by SQL query).

For example:
This is what I sent to the server:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(str); //str="12345"
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("Data", jsonString);
        PostClient proxy = new PostClient(parameters);
        proxy.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://justrun.comlu.com/JsonParse.php", UriKind.Absolute));
```

**UPDATE**
This is what I use in PHP server:

```
$a=$_POST['Data'];
echo "<ServerResponse>";
echo $a;
echo "</ServerResponse>";
```

This is what it printed out:

```
<ServerResponse>\"12345\"</ServerResponse>
```

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 project and I'm new to both C#, JSON and especially PHP. This thing is really annoying to me, and it would take me a lot of time to edit the string. Could somebody please explain this?

Comment: Try using single quotes like this, see if it helps `string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject('12345');` or try escaping it like this `string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(\"12345\");`

Comment: From what I saw in your edit, I think you should be doing `$str=12345` since it's an integer and not a string, unless that is what your intention is. If so, try using `$str='12345'` and you might need to add a semi-colon `;` at end. I.e.: `$str='12345';`

Comment: oh it's a Json string, but I need to get rid of the "\" problem so I could parse it into PHP object. These code must be wrote on .NET C# not on PHP. I tried your solutions but it doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried, I wish you well, cheers.

Comment: I've read your answers again and realized maybe the problem came from my progress on server side. I've updated my PHP server code.

Comment: Is your `12345` coming in from `$a=$_POST['Data'];` ?

Comment: yes, it is. I got the string that be printed out into my Windows Phone application, cut the <ServerResponse> tag away

Comment: It's hard for me to say. The only thing I can think of is, if your data is enclosed inside double quotes, try wrapping it inside single quotes or none at all. For example `$a=$_POST[Data];`

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work either. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [disable PHP magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

This is [a deprecated feature](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) that exists just to cause trouble. You should upgrade PHP too.